# Select where not exist in interval ? Different between four dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, data-access-layer

In the first the business is car rental system .

I want to get all car where has no orders in interval selected by user

```
public List<Car> SearchCar(DateTime pickdate, DateTime dropdate)
{
    var db = new CarRentalDBEntities();
    var temp = new List<Car>();

    temp = db.Cars.Where(item => 

       !item.Orders.Any
        (e => e.PickUpDateTime >= pickdate && dropdate  <= e.DropDataTime)

        ).ToList();

    return temp;
}
```

this is the last code I write

- the error is : cars still comes if order intersect with interval user choosed

Comment: You need to add more conditions; if your date range is january, youre only checkign for cars rented and returned in jan,. What about rented in jan, returned in feb.. or taken in dec, returned injan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you probably want to be checking if either the pickup date is in the range or the return date is in the range, or if the rental period is longer than the entire range:

```
e => (pickdate <= e.PickUpDateTime && e.PickUpDateTime < dropdate) || //picked up in period
     (pickdate <= e.DropDataTime && e.DropDataTime < dropdate) || //dropped off in period
     (e.PickUpDateTime < pickdate && e.DropDataTime > dropdate) //rental spans period
```

Notes: typo in your DropDat**a**Time

Comment: Thanks peter-- think it was a highlight + ctrl-drag to copy, and I forgot to do the ctrl part so it ended up a move.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are trying to do,

*I made the following modifications*

- I used `All` instead of `!Any` i find it easier to read
- I put the Db Context In a `using` statement, good practice
- I returned the output directly (no need for temp variable)

The premise as i understand it is to return all cars not and order

```
public List<Car> SearchCar(DateTime pickdate, DateTime dropdate)
{
   using (var db = new CarRentalDBEntities())
   {
       return db.Cars.Where(item => item.Orders.All(e =>
               // where order pickup date is less Pick or greater than drop
           (e.PickUpDateTime < pickdate || e.PickUpDateTime > dropdate) &&
               // where order Drop date is less Pick or greater than drop
           (e.DropDataTime < pickdate || e.DropDataTime > dropdate)))
               .ToList();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use:

```
var temp = db.Cars.Where(item => 
  item.Orders.All(e =>
  e.DropDataTime <= pickdate
  ||
  e.PickUpDateTime >= dropdate
  )
  ).ToList();
```

For all existing orders `e`, either they finish their order in time, or else they only need the car after.

This assumes that all existing orders `e` on the car are "sane" in the sense that their pick-up is earlier than their drop time.